# Did three people turn down a meeting in Zuckerberg's dorm room about founding Facebook?

Tags: united-states, facebook

I've seen this posted to Linkedin:

> Now this makes you think!! .....10 years ago, a student at Harvard
>   invited 5 people over to his dorm room to discuss a business
>   opportunity. Only 2 of the 5 people showed up. Today those two people
>   are Billionaires: Dustin Moskovitz $9.9 Billion and Eduardo Saverin
>   $5.8 Billion. And the guy they met that night? None other than Mark
>   Zuckerberg, CEO of Facebook, whose current net worth is: $35.7
>   Billion.  There's nothing more expensive than a missed opportunity

Sounds like an imaginary story to me! Did three people turn down this meeting? Did this event even happen?

Comment: The "imaginary" part of that seems to me that 2 out of 5 people would randomly decide to fund a person in a dorm room. Not only "lost opportunities" can cost money, but also engaging in an opportunity that you should stay away from.